# How to skip validation in chageset pipeline

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

With the given example of simple changeset:

```
def changeset(struct, params \\ %{}) do
  struct
  |> cast(params, [:email, :password])
  |> validate_required([:email, :password])
  |> validate_something
end
```

What would be the best way to skip `validate_something/1` validation if previous one, `validate_required/3`, is failed?

Most obvious is to wrap everything inside `if/else` statement like:

```
defp validate_something(changeset) do
  if changeset.valid? do
    ...
  else
    changeset
  end
end
```

But I would prefer to use something like guard clause without [arrowing](http://wiki.c2.com/?ArrowAntiPattern) my code even more.

Answer (score 4):

Found a better way:

```
defp validate_something(%{valid?: true} = changeset) do
  ...
end
defp validate_something(changeset), do: changeset
```